# Install TRibbon Delphi Berlin update 2

Tags: delphi, ribbon, delphi-10.1-berlin

How to install tribbon manually in delphi Berlin update 2?

PS: TRibbon Donwload link?

Thx.

Comment: As you know, nowadays, Tribbon is installed via "Getit", mine does not work, so i need to install manually.

Comment: +one to compensate for the downvotes. Always explain your downvotes.

Comment: From Embarcadero's help: "Note: The Vcl.Ribbon unit is not included in the RAD Studio installation, it must be installed separately using the GetIt Package Manager"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [TurboPack's Ribbon Framework](https://github.com/TurboPack/RibbonFramework). This library will allow you to implement the type TUIRibbon. There are instructions on how to add a TUIRibbon are on the GitHub page. There is [a wiki](https://github.com/TurboPack/RibbonFramework/wiki) with more detailed instructions.

To install it: (instructions from GitHub)

- Download the library
- Open the project "Package\UIRibbonPackage.dproj"
- Right click "UIRibbonPackage" and click "install"
- "Tools > Options > Environment Options > Delphi Options > Library > Library Path > [...]" Browse to the "Lib" folder of this framework, press "OK", "Add", "OK", "OK"

Hope that helps.